# Wildfly and Mybatis with Lazy Loading Exception

Tags: java, lazy-loading, classloader, mybatis, wildfly

The problem I'm Experiencing is similar to the following: [Jboss Wildfly EJB3 and Mybatis Deployment Error: NoSuchMethodError javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687423/jboss-wildfly-ejb3-and-mybatis-deployment-error-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persist/26687474#26687474) but it does not stop me from deploying my EAR, my problem occurs when trying to execute a method in my DAO which uses a MyBatis mapper with a Lazy Load reference to another mapper. I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot enable lazy loading because CGLIB is not available. Add CGLIB to your classpath.
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:111) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:102) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:98) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at coza.healthbridge.sharedservices.dao.AbstractDAO.getAll(AbstractDAO.java:141) [shared-services-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 215 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot enable lazy loading because CGLIB is not available. Add CGLIB to your classpath.
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.loader.cglib.CglibProxyFactory.<init>(CglibProxyFactory.java:56) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getProxyFactory(Configuration.java:300) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:523) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:334) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:294) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:269) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:239) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:153) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:60) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:73) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doQuery(BatchExecutor.java:87) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:137) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:96) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:77) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:108) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    ... 253 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/Type
    at net.sf.cglib.core.TypeUtils.parseType(TypeUtils.java:184) [cglib.jar:]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.<clinit>(KeyFactory.java:66) [cglib.jar:]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69) [cglib.jar:]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:178) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:89) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.classForName(Resources.java:256) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.loader.cglib.CglibProxyFactory.<init>(CglibProxyFactory.java:54) [mybatis.jar:3.2.8]
    ... 268 more
```

My pom.xml has the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Proxy support (Mandatory) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- Internal dependency (Required) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- Internal dependency (Required) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
    <artifactId>oscache</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <!-- This excludes the transitive dependency on JMS -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This is really tricky as with the **exact** same EAR in Jboss 7 the method works. I also know that there is a module in the jboss base system built in for asm (module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="asm.asm"). If i add the asm.jar back into my EAR i get the deployment error from the post mentioned above because the asm module is loaded by jboss itself. Since the application works in JBoss 7 i know that my mybatis-config.xml, mappers and entity POJOS are fine. My Guess is this is some sort of JBoss *Wildfly* classloading specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my own solution to the problem since i couldnt find an answer anywhere for my issue.

After Researching how the JBoss Wildfly Class Loading works I came across the Global Modules concept https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly (scroll to Global Modules Heading).

After a bit of tweaking and fiddling with my standalone.xml I found the solution.

You have to search for the java ee subsystem (*regardless of version* urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0 **or** urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0) and add a global-modules tag for the asm.asm module like so:

```
<global-modules>
    <module name="asm.asm" slot="main" />
</global-modules>
```

After restarting my jboss with the asm.asm module as a Global module my application functioned as it used to in JBoss 7.